# How do I stain carpet on minecraft pe survival?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Right now I'm trying to put black carpet on the board walk bedroom on my survival seed. The only problem is the fact that I can only obtain RED carpet. Can I stain it or can I only have red? If I can stain it, please tell me how. Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to think of a witty answer involving red wine...

Answer (score 1):

In [Minecraft Pocket Edition](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition), only red carpet is available in survival mode, but all colours are available in creative mode as you can see in the Creative inventory:

[image: Carpet]

Other options for a black floor could include:

[Obsidian](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Obsidian):[image: Obsidian][Blocks of Coal](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Block_of_Coal):[image: Coal]

Both of these blocks can be obtained in survival mode.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, only red carpet is currently obtainable in Minecraft Pocket Edition.